# How to change the blank elements in a csv file to zeroes in Python with strip()?

Tags: python, strip

I'm writing a program that reads from an excel file then writes data to a text file. The function in question is supposed to perform a mathematical equation but I'm getting:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

because the 3 "loans" columns have some empty cells instead of zeroes.

I asked my professor for help and they said I should use `strip()` and `if` statements but I'm not sure how I'd implement it. I tried making `if` statements under the original functions they were in but after I made the `return` statement, the original `return` statement in the function obviously became uncallable. I tried other things but had no success. I did look up similarly worded questions but no luck there either.

Here are the two functions that get errors:

```
def debt_service_ratio(salary, loan1, loan2, loan3):
    pay = float(salary)
    mortgage = float(loan1)
    personal_loans = float(loan2)
    student_loans = float(loan3)
    t_owed = mortgage + personal_loans + student_loans
    return'Total Debt Service Ratio: ' + str(t_owed / pay)
```

and

```
debt_service_ratio(row[3], row[5], row[6], row[7])
```

So I specifically would like to know how you can use the `strip` function to do this but I also wouldn't mind knowing any other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need conditions in your function like:

```
if loan1.strip(): #if stripping all spaces from loan1 gives a non-empty string
    mortgage = float(loan1)
else: #else if it is an empty string
    mortgage = 0
```

Do this for all variables that may be empty.